# Total Amount on basis of LIKE in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Please help me out as I am not getting a correct Amount.

```
=IIF(Fields!CurCAT.Value LIKE "14*",SUM(Fields!CurAmount.Value),0)
```

When i used the Like in SQL Server Query 
e.g

```
UG.GroupCat LIKE '14%'
```

it throws me two different amounts i.e

```
141 | -249278084408.667
142 | -250662239528.2
```

Now in SSRS Report i need to sum up those two amounts and show the result in the cell but its not giving me a correct amount.

Comment: What is the result in SSRS?

Comment: Pretty sure the SUM is giving you sum of entire amounts, not just the ones with CurCAT values starting with 14.

Comment: Could you do this sum in the SQL query and use the summed column in your report rather the trying to SUM in SSRS?

Comment: @Shruti no its not giving me its giving an error if i use SUM(IIF(....

Comment: @Shruti it gives me includes an aggregate ....

Comment: @JohnHC Its giving me only one amount

Comment: @JohnHC the first one or second me its not totaling up

Answer (score 0):

Your `IIF` expression needs to be your `SUM` expression, not the other way around.

You are looking for something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CurCAT.Value LIKE "14*", Fields!CurAmount.Value, 0))
```

Comment: Did this answer help at all?